# Reusing entry in bibliography file with some modifications

Tags: bibtex

Lets say I have entry like this:

```
@book{FT-GT,
  author={Drew Fudenberg and Jean Tirole},
  title={{G}ame {T}heory},
  publisher={The MIT Press},
  year={1991},
  address={Cambridge}
}
```

I now that I can quote it like `\cite{FT-GT}` and it will all be generated smoothly. But what if I wanted to achieve something like:

```
@book{FT-GT-DEF1,
  author={Drew Fudenberg and Jean Tirole},
  title={{G}ame {T}heory},
  publisher={The MIT Press},
  year={1991},
  address={Cambridge},
  pages={50--55}
}

@book{FT-GT-DEF2,
  author={Drew Fudenberg and Jean Tirole},
  title={{G}ame {T}heory},
  publisher={The MIT Press},
  year={1991},
  address={Cambridge},
  pages={66--67}
}

% FT-GT-DEF3, FT-GT-DEF4, and so on...
```

Would I be able to obtain it without copy-pasting and modifying previous entries? Is there some smart way to achieve several quotations from the same book/article without typing several times the same information over and over?

Comment: It's the same reference; use `\cite[p.~50--55]{FT-GT}` for the first citation and similarly for the other ones.

Comment: Thanks! I did't know how to formulate my question so I didn't know how can I google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not different bibliographic references, but different citations of the same reference. So you should have only one entry in the bibliography, say

```
@book{FT-GT,
  author={Drew Fudenberg and Jean Tirole},
  title={Game {Theory}},
  publisher={The MIT Press},
  year={1991},
  address={Cambridge}
}
```

and, in the body of the document, something like

```
\cite[p.~50--55]{FT-GT}

\cite[p.~66--67]{FT-GT}
```

for emphasizing which part of the book you're specifically referring to.

Note that the title field should be

```
title={Game Theory},
```

leaving the decision about capitalization to the bibliographic style. If you really want to preserve the original capitalization, use

```
title={Game {Theory}},
```

In this case it's not really different, because there's no kerning between `T` and `h`; but in cases such as `Te` the kerning would be impossible if `{T}e` was used.
The first letter in a title is never changed.

Comment: On the capitalization of the words in the book's title: No BibTeX bibliography style I've ever come across applies "sentence style" to the `title` field of an entry of type `@book`. Instead, all styles employ "title style," i.e., any existing capitalization in the field is taken on board one for one. Thus, `title={Game Theory},` should be just fine.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment; but, as you see, my advice was *not* adding braces. `;-)`

Comment: I know. :-) I just thought it might be worth stating the *reason* for not using extra braces in this case, *viz.*, the fact that "title style" is applied to the `title` field of entries of type `@book`.

Comment: The one I was using did that, since in my native language we do use sentence capitalization for titles. ;) For our literature it's fine but for English I have to use that workaround.